# Using max() function with entity framework throws an exception

Tags: entity-framework, max

So I need to get the max value of a column (or the last one) using entity framework and both of these queries throw exceptions:

(The ID I'm trying to retrieve is of type varchar, but it works in raw sql, I think
it should work here too)

This one:

```
string maxCurrentID = db.reservations.Max().ReservationID;
```

Throws this:

The specified method 'EntityClub_.reservacion Maxreservacion' on the type 'System.Linq.Queryable' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression because no overload matches the passed arguments.

and this one:

```
 string maxCurrentID = db.reservations.LastOrDefault().ReservationID;
```

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'EntityClub_.reservacion LastOrDefaultreservacion' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

How can I obtain the expected values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't asking for the highest ReservationID, you're trying to get the highest Reservation, and getting its ReservationID. EF does not understand what "the highest Reservation" means.

```
var maxReservationID = db.reservations.Max(r => r.ReservationID);
```

or

```
var maxReservationID = db.reservations.Select(r => r.ReservationID).Max();
```

should work.

Answer (score 19):

```
var maxReservationId=db.reservations.Max(u =>(int?)u.ReservationID) ?? 0;
```

if there is no data in table it replaces `null` with `0`

Comment: This is the best answer since it cares about empty tables.

Comment: Well, if it's not a nullable it will default to 0 anyway, so this answer is only relevant IF the value is a nullable, which should make the (int?) cast redundant.

Comment: @SimonAronsson - In EF Core 2.0, without casting to nullable int and then null coalescing to 0, `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements.'` is thrown if the table is empty instead of returning 0. So this answer was exactly what I needed in my case.

Comment: Nice one @sanjeet, I was using default if empty which isn't very intuitive, glad to know that casting to int? works.